# I cant install the toolkit srilm on linux mint

Tags: linux, srilm

I have downloaded toolkit srilm from it's homepage : http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/download.html

After i unpacked it, there wasn't the file ngram-count in the location srilm/bin/i686.

Can anybody help me?What went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the smt_installer on github:

https://github.com/prites18/smt_installer.git

Just select the srilm option from Advanced configuration. You can also install moses, moses2, irstlm, etc with this tool.
I know I am answering quite late, but hope this helps.